# What's the answer to this indeterminated limit?

Tags: calculus

The exercise  says that in order that

\begin{equation*}
g(x) =\frac{1-\cos( 3x-9)}{( x-3)^{2}} +\frac{x}{6}
\end{equation*}
be continuous at $x=3$, then $g(3)$ should be...

I understand that for a function to be continuous at a point, the limit should be equal to evaluate the function at that point. 
I solved this in two different ways and each gives me a different answer.
[Solution 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kj5cK.jpg)   [Solution 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeucR.jpg)

The graphic is hard to analyze, so I can't get an answer from there.
I appreciate the help, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Note that from $\cos(2a)=1-2\sin^2 a$,
 $$1-\cos(3x-9)=2\sin^2\frac{3(x-3)}{2}$$
thus
$$\lim_{x\to 3}g(x)=\lim_{x\to 3}2\left(\frac{\sin\frac{3(x-3)}{2}}{x-3}\right)^2+\lim_{x\to 3}\frac{x}{6}\\
=\frac{9}{4}\lim_{x\to 3}2\left(\frac{\sin\frac{3(x-3)}{2}}{\frac{3(x-3)}{2}}\right)^2+\frac12\\
=\frac92+\frac12=2$$
thus $g(3)=5$.

Comment: The denominator in the first line after ‘thus’ should be $(x-3)$ (not squared).

Comment: @Bernard thanks.Edoted

Comment: And the factor at the second line is not $\frac 34$.

Comment: if 
\begin{gather*}
\sin^{2} x+\cos^{2} x=1\\
\sin^{2} x=1-\cos^{2} x
\end{gather*}
then 
$\displaystyle \sin^{2}( 3x-9) =1-Cos( 3x-9)$
?

Comment: That's almost correct (the cosine has to be squared).

Comment: You forgot the big fraction is squared.

Comment: @Angelo Fariña check the edit

Comment: Thanks!
why  in the second line $\displaystyle x-3$ and not $\displaystyle ( x-3)^{2}$?

Comment: We gather $(x-3)^2$ and $\sin^2 3(x-3)/2$ in a bracket to the power of $2$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

A standard limit is 
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1-\cos t}{t^2}=\frac  12,\quad\text{whence }\;\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1-\cos at}{t^2}=\lim_{t\to 0}a^2\frac{1-\cos at}{(at)^2}=\frac{a^2} 2.$$
Now, in $g(x)$, set $\;t=x-3$.
Can you proceed?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand it and what are you trying to say.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: If $\displaystyle t=x-3$ then $\displaystyle \lim _{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{1-\cos( 3( x-3))}{( x-3)^{2}} =\lim _{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{1-\cos( 3t)}{t^{2}}$ ?
I don't understand why did u multiplied by $\displaystyle a^{2}$ and $\displaystyle ( at)^{2}$ in the denominator.

Comment: It is to have exactly the argument of the cosine inside the square in the denominator, so the limit of the fraction is $\frac12$. To compensate, I had to multiply by $a^2$ in the numerator. Is it clear?

Comment: Yes. In my case it will be $\displaystyle \lim _{t\rightarrow 0} 3^{2}\frac{1-\cos( 3t)}{( 3t)^{2}}$ ? But why this is equal to $\displaystyle \frac{a^{2}}{2}$ ?

Comment: Because of the limit in the basic formula ($1/2$). If you know Taylor's formula, this becomes obvious.

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{9(1-\cos (3x-9)}{9(x-3)^2)}=$

$9\dfrac{(1-\cos (3x-9))(1+\cos (3x-9))}{(3x-9)^2(1+\cos (3x-9))}$

$=9\dfrac{\sin^2 (3x-9)}{(3x-9)^2(1+\cos (3x-9))}$;

$g(x)=$

$9\dfrac{\sin^2 (3x-9)}{(3x-9)^2}\dfrac{1}{(1+\cos (3x-9))}+ \dfrac{x}{6}$

Take the limit.

Note: $\lim_{y \rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\sin^2 y}{y^2}=1.$

Comment: I didn't understand where the 9 came from. But I was able to follow the rest. Thanks!

Comment: Angela. Denominator: Originally $(x-3)^2$.  Multiplying denominator and numerator by 9 does not change the value of the fraction. Now we have $9(x-3)^2=3^2(x-3)^2=(3(x-3))^2=(3x-9)^2=:y$. Now you can use $(\sin^2 y)/y^2$. Changed the denominator to be able to use this formula.ok?